# 64Bit Required for Microsoft Emulators fro windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

Is it necessary to have 64bit Windows 10 version for installing mobile emulators for win10??
Also,While trying to install it through the installer package of VS2015 I can't find options for Microsoft Mobile Emulators..I don't know what really is needed for having Emulators installed on my system..

Comment: The mobile emulators require Hyper-V, which requires a 64-bit host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every information, sdk and guide can be found at [https://dev.windows.com/](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads). A little research on that site will allow you to check the [emulator requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt188754.aspx):

[image]